# I want to add some specifict font to my app. I want to know, what is a font on android developer example

Tags: android, fonts, colors, android-toolbar

[image]

On this picture from android developer site, we can see a using of card layout. But they used some specific font there. On images there are some strings with this font. What is a font?

And if you can, tell me, how to implement a transparent toolbar, as in the picture?

Thanks

Comment: So your question is a) What is "a" font? b) What is the name of the font in the picture? c) How to implement a transparent toolbar? ... please choose one.

Comment: @ElDuderino, thanks for your reply and sorry for my English... What is a name of the font in the picture with text "Kangaroo Valleys Safari"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font on the pictures is [Roboto Slab](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Slab)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Alex!